# Using python to develop web application

Tags: python

I have been doing some work in python, but that was all for stand alone applications. I'm curious to know whether any offshoot of python supports web development?

Would some one also suggest a good tutorial or a website from where I can pick up some of the basics of web development using python?

Comment: If I hear the words DJango or TurboGears or whatever anymore ... im gonna ... do something crazy?

Comment: @Aiden ... then I'd recommend staying away form any discussions of python web apps, because *not* talking about the major frameworks in the context of web development is "something crazy".

Comment: @Aaron, the comment was in humour. I have some spare if you want it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Now that everyone has said [Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/), I can add my two cents: I would argue that you might learn more by looking at the different components first, before using Django. For web development with Python, you often want 3 components:

1. Something that takes care
   of the HTTP stuff (e.g.
   [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/))
2. A templating language
   to create your web pages.
   [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/)
   is very pythonic and [works](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/progguide/choosingtemplate.html) with Cherrpy.
3. If you get your data from a
   database, an ORM comes in handy.
   [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)
   would be an [example](https://bitbucket.org/Lawouach/cherrypy-recipes/src/c8290261eefb/web/database/sql_alchemy/).

All the links above have good tutorials. For many real-world use-cases, Django will be a better solution than such a stack as it seamlessly integrates this functionality (and more). And if you need a CMS, Django is your best bet short of Zope. Nevertheless, to get a good grasp of what's going on, a stack of loosely coupled programs might be better. Django hides a lot of the details.

Comment: +1 SQLAlchemy is very cool (though, django+etc have the benefit of already picking the dispatcher, ORM, Template language so that you don't have to).

Comment: @Aaron: totally, agree. Amended answer to make this advantage of Django clearer

Answer (score 4):

**Edited 3 years later**: Don't use mod_python, use mod_wsgi. Flask and Werkzeug are good frameworks too. Needing to know what's going on is useful, but it isn't a requirement. That would be stupid.

Don't lookup Django until you have a good grasp of what Django is doing on your behalf. for you. Write some basic apps using mod_python and it's request object. I just started learning Python for web-development using mod_python and it has been great.

mod_python also uses a dispatcher in site-packages/mod_python/publisher.py. Have a ganders through this to see how requests can be handled in a simple-ish way.

You may need to add a bit of config to your Apache config file to get mod_python up and running but the mod_python site explains it well.

```
<Directory /path/to/python/files>
     AddHandler mod_python .py
     PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
     PythonDebug On
</Directory>
```

And you are away!

use (as a stupidly basic example):

```
def foo(req):
    req.write("Hello World")
```

in `/path/to/python/files/bar.py` assuming `/path/to` is your site root.

And then you can do

```
http://www.mysite.com/python/files/bar/foo
```

to see "Hello World". Also, something that **tripped me up** is the dispatcher uses a lame method to work out the content-type, so to force HTML use:

```
req.content_type = 'text/html'
```

**Good Luck**

After you have a good idea of how Python interacts with mod_python and Apache, then use a framework that does all the boring stuff for you. Up to you though, just my recommendation

Comment: If you insist on suggesting that people roll their own, you should at least suggest that they use WSGI and not mod_python. WSGI is the standard for writing python web apps and does not lock you in to the API of a specific webserver (as common as that webserver may be). Furthermore, as you discover some of the pain of writing a webapp from scratch WSGI leaves the door open to reuse other WSGI components.

Comment: Given that the OP is used to standalone development in Python, and requested "basics of web development using python" this seemed like the appropriate place to start, having started this way myself and found it a great foundation to build on.

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't want to delve into the frameworks - and you should, I heartily recommend Django or Pylons - there's still need to go down the road of CGI. This is a totally out-of-date technology, not to mention slow and inefficient.

There *is* a standard way of building Python web applications, and it's called [WSGI](http://www.wsgi.org/). If you want to roll your own web app from scratch, this is absolutely the way to go.

That said, if you're just starting out, really you should go with one of the frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

[Python Wiki: Web Frameworks for Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks)

If you decide to use [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), [the official tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) is an excellent place to start. [The Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/) is also free.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of choices for web development. From my experience, your choice will again be dependent on your application. I used [django](http://djangoproject.com) and [web.py](http://webpy.org/) in production and I am about to deploy an app based on [pylons](http://pylonshq.com/).

[Django](http://djangoproject.com) hides a lot of choices (comes with its ORM and templating). The documentation is extensive and well-written. There are many reusable app available for django, but you will likely to invest a little time in integrating them seamlessly. One thing [mentioned on djangocon 08](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fipFKyW2FA4) was the fact, that there is cool stuff in django, which can't be easily
accessed in non-django projects.

[web.py](http://webpy.org/) impressed me by its raw simplicity. Before I knew it, I wrote a small app ([78 lines quasi-wiki](http://myyn.org/localwiki)) in it.

[pylons](http://pylonshq.com/) feels like in the middle of both. I can use [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/), all in all a pleasant experience for the start.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup Django.

Answer (score 0):

Python can be used for web development, but there isn't a special language extension or anything in the language that will handle all the HTML generation or that works like PHP.

It's pretty much run through some sort of interpreter on a web server (CGI, mod_python, etc.).

I would recommend looking into [Python Web Application Frameworks](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) or how to write [Python CGI scripts](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts).

Answer (score 0):

There are [quite a few](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks) web frameworks for python out there, but the only one I've used is [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), and I really like it.

If you've got a few hours, do the [tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/), I promise you, you'll enjoy it :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, one of the more prominent python "offshoots" as you call them would be [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/).  It is a rather powerful framework that allows you to quickly and securely build web applications.  The first place to look would be [their overview](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/overview/#intro-overview) which gives some insight as to what Django does as a framework.

Going through [their tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) taught me alot about the prominent Model-View-Controler design pattern and how it may be used in a web-development context.  I found it a great way to start writing an application that worked and learn by improving it.