# Are there good Tutorials on how to make web apps with Python?

Tags: python

I think I'm gonna start learning Python web development from scratch. So if someone knows good tutorials on this, please post links.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641616/python-and-web-development , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209092/python-web-programming

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895420/using-python-to-develop-web-application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean "learn from scratch" and not "build from scratch", these are books for popular frameworks:

- [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/)
- [Pylons Book](http://pylonsbook.com/)
- [Zope Book](http://www.zope.org/Documentation/Books/ZopeBook/)

There are many others, so do some searching around.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of choices, just to name a few:

**Frameworks**

- [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/documentation/) / [Screencast](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/wiki30/) (building a wiki)
- [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) / [Screencasts](http://www.throwingbeans.org/django_screencasts.html) ..
- [web.py](http://webpy.org/) (a minimalistic framework)

**Standards**

- [PEP-0333, the web server gateway interface (WSGI)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/), [Techtalk on WSGI](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-872784530622495809&ei=gEEuS67NPNq8-AbTnfTeAw&q=wsgi&hl=en)

**Further reading**

- [Web Programming in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebProgramming)

**Example** of a web application written with the [webpy](http://webpy.org/) framework:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'hello'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:        
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name: 
            name = 'world'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

[Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) is a toolkit for writing web applications Python.

The [Django Tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

[A beginner's Python Tutorial](http://www.sthurlow.com/python/)

[Official python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial)

[Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.org/)

[alt text http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51AouTH6QpL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51AouTH6QpL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [Lynda python 3](http://www.lynda.com/Python-3-tutorials/essential-training/62226-2.html?srchtrk=index%3A1%0Alinktypeid%3A2%0Aq%3Apython%0Apage%3A1%0As%3Arelevance%0Asa%3Atrue%0Aproducttypeid%3A2), I am learning python myself too and it has been awesome. Is in video so i think the learning process speeds up.